# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an error while rendering the following component:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
     
function My() {
  const [NAME, setValue_] = useState([{name:"",lname:""}]);  //      usestate
  let arr = [{ name: "man", lname: "Kumar" }];    //.......creating array for passing to set the value for State..
      
  setValue_(arr); //............passing array to Update data......

  console.log(NAME);   //..........Want to see updated Data....
        
  return(<> </>) //............... i didn't return anything........
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be doing `setValue_` on some event. Since, JS/React runs your code line by line and you have `setValue_` in open. So, on every render you are basically calling `setValue_` which is causing infinite render issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304283/error-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-prevent-an-in)

Comment: thanks bro...from heart

Comment: i am new in web development

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
     
function My() {
  const [name, setName] = useState([{ name: "man", lname: "Kumar" }]); 
        
  return(<>helloworld</>)
}
```

That's it. Just pass the array directly to the state instead of updating it later.If you really need to play it this way, then use a useEffect. Also, please keep a naming consistency. setValue doesn't relate well to name.

Comment: what is problem behind my infinite loop

Comment: The component render => you update the state outside a lifecycle method, a function or an event => the component re-renders => etc.

Comment: Please validate this answer in case someone else encounter the same issue ;).