# Why react throws "Too many re-renders.", if we try to change state on a On Click function itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react hooks for last few days, but i cannot figure it out why I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loo
```

use state variables

```
 const [count, setSamplePageData] = useState(0);
```

changing state in onclick

```
<button className="btn-primary" onClick={setSamplePageData(1)}>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/so-hyji1k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `onClick={() => setSamplePageData(1)}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304283/error-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-prevent-an-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `setSamplePageData` and passing it the argument `1` during the render step. (Which triggers a new render, which calls the function again, ad infinitum).

Then you're passing the return value of that (which is, IIRC, `undefined`) to `onClick`.

You need to pass a *function* to `onClick`.

```
 const [count, setSamplePageData] = useState(0);
 const clickHandler = () => setSamplePageData(1);
 // ...
 <button className="btn-primary" onClick={clickHandler}>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because setSamplePageData is instantly called upon render and when you set state you trigger render event thus creating infinite loop.

Instead define a inline function in onClick event

```
<button className="btn-primary" onClick={() => setSamplePageData(1)}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because if you don't use the parenthesis react call function on every render and it will cause so many re-renders you should change your onClick event handler to this

```
onClick={() => setSamplePageData(params)}
```

these parentheses in onClick prevents the function from being called on every render.