# React, using setState causes infinite loop error

Tags: reactjs

I'm taking an intro to React course and just trying to accomplish something similar that I saw in my training. I'm trying to pull data from an API endpoint, make a little change to the data and then use setState to update the value of a variable that will hold the new data set.

The API returns a data set like this:

```
{
    "site1": [
      "device-a01",
      "device-a02",
      "device-b01",
      "device-b02"
    ],
    "site2": [
      "device-a01",
      "device-a02",
      "device-b01",
      "device-b02",
      "device-c01",
      "device-c02"
    ]
}
```

I need to iterate through this object and create an array variable that should look like this:

```
const tableData = [
    [
      "site1", "device-a01", 
      "site1", "device-a02",
      "site1", "device-b01", 
      "site1", "device-b02",
      "site2", "device-a01", 
      "site2", "device-a02",
      "site2", "device-b01", 
      "site2", "device-b02",
      "site2", "device-c01", 
      "site2", "device-c02"
    ]
```

My code:

```
import React from "react"

const [dataSet2, setDataSet2] = React.useState([])
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await fetch("https://url.com/api/devices/")
      const data = await res.json()
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
      setDataSet2(data)
    }
    getData()
  },[])


  Object.entries(dataSet2).map(([key, value]) => {
    value.map(hub => {
      buildTableData(key, hub)
    })
  })

  function buildTableData(key, value) {
    // console.log(key, value)
    const hubValue = key + "," + value
    console.log(hubValue) // prints the data to the console as i need it to be.

    // this causes the infinit loop error
    setTableData( prevData => ({
      ...prevData,
      hubValue
    }))
  }
```

I found some articles about this infinite loop error but they were pertaining to calling setState inside an event handler ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304283/error-too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-prevent-an-in)), not sure if it's related to what I'm trying to do, and if it is, then I don't know how to fix it code wise in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build table data in `useEffect`. I advise you to prepare all data and update `setDataSet2` and `setTableData` at the end:

```
import React from "react"

const [dataSet2, setDataSet2] = React.useState([])
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([])

function buildTableData(key, value) {
  // console.log(key, value)
  const hubValue = key + "," + value
  console.log(hubValue) // prints the data to the console as i need it to be.

  return {
    ...prevData,
    hubValue
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://url.com/api/devices/")
    const data = await res.json()
    
    const _tableData = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
        return value.map(hub => buildTableData(key, hub)) // here is the fix
    })
    
    setTableData(_tableData);
    setDataSet2(data);
  }
  getData()
},[])
```

Comment: this did not work. FYI, I tweaked your code a little by removing "...prevData" since that is not valid anymore. when I try to console.log(_tableData) before calling setTableData(_tableData) it returns undefined for all elements.

Comment: @stminion001 You can create a codesandbox (or another) example ?

Comment: Ahh, my mistake: when create table data not return values. I fix it

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
import React from "react"

const [dataSet2, setDataSet2] = React.useState([])
const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://url.com/api/devices/").then(res => setDataSet2(res.data))
}, [])

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!tableData) {
        let results = []
        Object.entries(dataSet2).map(([key, value]) => {
            return value.map(hub => {
                results.push(key)
                results.push(hub)
            })
        })
        setTableData(results)
    }
}, [dataSet2])
```